# next/image how to use getInitialProps or get router details on load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cypress, nextjs-image

I am trying to access query params on page initialization and to be able to force certain pages to pre-load images. This is actually for testing and snapshots, as I want to turn lazy load off and have all images load from the start. However with next/image I am unable to use getInitialProps it appears and using the hook is too slow.

```
import { default as NextImage, ImageProps } from "next/image"

const Image = ({
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
      <NextImage
        {...props}
        priority={!!props.someQueryParam}
      />
  )
}

Image.getInitialProps = ({ query, ...rest }) => {
  console.info({ query })
  return { query }
}

export { Image }
```

I wonder if there is a way to be able to get the `InitaialProps` for the image component.

Comment: Have you looked into [cypress-wait-until](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until)?

Comment: Just want to point out that `getInitialProps` can only be used from pages and not components.

Comment: Thanks @KevinAshworth I haven't, I wonder if I can do something like `cy.waitUntil(() => cy.get("img").then` and catch all images? Interesting indeed